# Change function only called on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-5, html.dropdownlistfor

I have this dropdown

```
   Sort by: @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SortBy, Model.LotSortings, "Relevance", new { @class = "form-control", @id="sort_ddl" })
```

and I want to call a get action method (not an Ajax method) whenever I change the selection from one option to a different one.

I'd love to be shown how I can solve that too but as a first step towards this goal I created this script at the top of the page

```
<script>
    $('#sort_ddl').change(function () { alert('hi'); })
</script>
```

This does get called but only on page load and at that point it does not alert.  It never gets called on selection change.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add your method in `document.ready` function. It will attach the change `event` to element when DOM is ready.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#sort_ddl').change(function () {
            alert('hi');
        })
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also try:

```
<script>
   $(document).ready(function () {
      $('#sort_dll').on('change', function() {
         alert( 'hi' );
      })
   });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

For dynamically added  , use `.on`

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('body').on('#sort_ddl','change' ,function () {
            alert('hi');
        })
    });
</script>
```